# Schedule and Send reports automatically using asp.net vb

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I want to create a scheduler to email reports automatically in asp.net vb. I will set  parameter for report and save it in the database. This report will be send automatically on the scheduled time. 
I need some guidelines to start working on it. How will I send it OR how the system will recognize the schedule time and email the report.

Comment: Why not reuse the built-in scheduler of the Crystal Reports server? Unless your question is not related to CR Server but only to individual CR documents without a server environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go automatically, you will need to create a window application not asp.net. You can simply add a window application to generate crystal report and send mail.

Now how it will work automatically, you need to create a window task as below any of one links. In that you can give your exe path and give date and time schedule to run this exe.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/

http://www.techsupportalert.com/how_to_schedule_programs_to_run_automatically.htm

In asp.net side, this can not do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are free crystal reports schedulers. Why do you need to rediscover the hot water:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx
http://www.groffautomation.com/